# How to properly add extra layers to a dictionary (or better alternative)

Tags: python

In my program, I ask a user to make choices. These choices then pull data from Key/Nested Key/Value locations in the dictionary, which then make a calculation. I currently have a lot of dictionaries that I have created in one of my files, but would ideally like to narrow it down into one (or at least less) dictionary/ies because I believe this will allow the rest of the code to be written more smoothly moving on.

I would like to know how to properly add layers to dictionaries OR.. is there a better alternative than dictionaries?

I currently have many of these:

```
nameofdict = { 'KEY': 'NESTED KEY': 'VALUE', 'NESTED KEY': 'VALUE'},
               'KEY': 'NESTED KEY': 'VALUE', 'NESTED KEY': 'VALUE'}}
```

but would like something more like:

```
nameofdict = { 'KEY': {'NESTED KEY': {'DOUBLE NESTED KEY': 'VALUE', 'DOUBLE 
                NESTED KEY': 'VALUE'}},
               'KEY': {'NESTED KEY': {'DOUBLE NESTED KEY': 'VALUE', 'DOUBLE 
                NESTED KEY': 'VALUE'}}}
```

and ultimately be able to skip some levels if a certain "item" doesn't have that parameter, such as:

```
nameofdict = { 'KEY': {'NESTED KEY': {'DOUBLE NESTED KEY': 'VALUE', 'DOUBLE 
                NESTED KEY': 'VALUE'}},
               'KEY': {'NESTED KEY': {'DOUBLE NESTED KEY': 'VALUE', 'DOUBLE 
                NESTED KEY': 'VALUE'}},                      
                      {'NESTED KEY': {'DOUBLE NESTED KEY': 'VALUE', 'DOUBLE 
                NESTED KEY': 'VALUE'}}}
```

I've invested time with data entry and made a program to make nested dictionary creation easier and muchhh faster, so I'm trying to work with what I have already spent time in. I am just beginning to get familiar with all that Python has to offer and slowly making my code simpler and more consolidated as I learn the language.

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried already? It will be easier to optimize the solution you made. Though you may want to look into `defaultdict`.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I have tried what I wrote out in the question. The first one is proper syntax but I want to add more layers of nesting to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to declare the structure first and then you can use it

```
my_list = list()
my_dict = dict()
my_list.append(my_dict)
my_list[0]['KEY'] = dict()
my_list[0]['KEY']['NESTED KEY'] = dict()
my_list[0]['KEY']['NESTED KEY']['DOUBLE NESTED KEY'] = 'VALUE'

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'KEY': {'NESTED KEY': {'DOUBLE NESTED KEY': 'VALUE'}}}]
```

After if you need to add more object to your array, you can do it like this.

```
my_list = list()
my_dict1 = dict()
my_dict2 = dict()
my_list.append(my_dict1)
my_list.append(my_dict2)
my_list[0]['KEY'] = dict()
my_list[0]['KEY']['NESTED KEY'] = dict()
my_list[0]['KEY']['NESTED KEY']['DOUBLE NESTED KEY'] = 'VALUE1'
my_list[1]['KEY'] = dict()
my_list[1]['KEY']['NESTED KEY'] = dict()
my_list[1]['KEY']['NESTED KEY']['DOUBLE NESTED KEY'] = 'VALUE2'

print(my_list)
```

Output

```
[
  {'KEY': {'NESTED KEY': {'DOUBLE NESTED KEY': 'VALUE1'}}},
  {'KEY': {'NESTED KEY': {'DOUBLE NESTED KEY': 'VALUE2'}}}
]
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. Now I will just need to figure out how exactly it works. Am I correct that you're appending the list with the dictionary?

Comment: My pleasure, That is right, I append the dictionary into the list at first, then I append 2 dictionaries into that list again to show you the way to append more dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a creative way as well using `defaultdict`. This is short and will create the dict as needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
nest = nested_dict()
nest[0]['KEY']['NESTED KEY']['DOUBLE NESTED KEY'] = 'VALUE'
nest[1]['KEY']['NESTED KEY']['DOUBLE NESTED KEY'] = 'VALUE'
```

Then if you print it via:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(nest, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "0": {
        "KEY": {
            "NESTED KEY": {
                "DOUBLE NESTED KEY": "VALUE"
            }
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "KEY": {
            "NESTED KEY": {
                "DOUBLE NESTED KEY": "VALUE"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** A `defaultdict` will create an entry if it is not found. This can work against you in some cases. For example if I do:

```
bad_nest = nested_dict()
print(bad_nest[2]) # This will output {}, but will also add {2: {}} to the dict
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and response! I am currently working through the above answer to make sure I fully understand it and then I will go through this!